# plotly: axis "above traces" does not have an effect

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have been trying to plot axes above traces. This appears to be the default behavior (according to the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-layer)), and to be controlled by `layout.xaxis.layer`. Though, no matter the value of this property, it seems that the axes stay below the traces.

Minimal example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[-1,2,3], y=[-3,4,5], mode='lines'))
fig.update_xaxes(layer="above traces")
fig.update_yaxes(layer="above traces")
fig.show()
```

Result:
[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCpg2.png)

Plotly version: 5.8.0

Edit: The same happens if I use `plotly.express.line` for the plot and subsequently force the property assignment with `update_xaxes`.